# How to hide sql connection strings in aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The following is how I'm connecting.  Is there any way in Lambda to set environmental variables that aren't visible and ideally would cross to several lambdas?   Ideally in another AWS service that I could access with the SDK and use across all AWS services?

```
var MYSQL      = require('mysql');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var connection = MYSQL.createConnection({
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        port     : '3306',
        user     : 'myuser',
        password : 'mypass',
        database : 'mydb'
});
connection.connect();
```

Comment: Aren't visible by who/what exactly?

Comment: In the Lambda function code/configuration screen.  Id love to have an environmental variable for user and password.  

It would also keep the credentials abstract so it would be easy to change for a bunch of lambdas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that the answers given before experience some lack of relevance. The AWS recommended way of storing this sort of data like connection strings for lambda, is the [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html):

> AWS Systems Manager provides a centralized store to manage your
>   configuration data, whether plain-text data such as database strings
>   or secrets such as passwords. This enables you to separate your
>   secrets and configuration data from your code.

See also: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sharing-secrets-with-aws-lambda-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/

Comment: Yep. Thank you! This is it. I read about encrypted params as well.

Comment: the problem with the Parameter Store is that it provides relatively low throughput (40 transactions/second by default). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html. If your system has these request rates, some caching should be implemented

Comment: @evgpisarchik, You should be getting these values once per startup.  when we were getting multiple values, we used a JSON string.

Answer (score 3):

I would store that in either a DynamoDB table or an S3 bucket.  You can assign an IAM role to the Lambda to allow access to these - maybe read-only.

Alternatively, Lambda's now have environment variables like Elastic Beanstalk and you could set it that way.  They can be encrypted though that adds some complexity too.

Comment: Do you know if the environmental vars across lambdas or per lambda basis?  It looked like on a per lambda basis.

If not, the DynamoDB idea is probably what I'm looking for.  That way I can have sort of a distributed credentialing system like a 'low-rent ldap'.

Comment: The environment variables are per lambda as Dave said in his answer.  I've used a simple key/value table with an "environment" (dev, prod, etc.) to do this.  And "Low Rent LDAP" is a great band name!

Comment: Haha 'Low Rent LDAP' will always card at their gigs.  
Thanks much for the help! We're going all lambda for our API so we went with the Dynamo DB idea.  Although it was great to know about the Environmental Vars option in the lambdas it was just too daunting the idea of changing each one if we had to change the database creds.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use [encrypted environment variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html#env_encrypt).

Behind the scenes they will use [KMS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/) to encrypt the values and then will allow your Lambda functions to use them as if they were plain text within the container context.

Comment: This is great.  Much thanks for the help. Just wondering if theres any way the environment variable option would apply across multiple lambdas or are they on a per lambda basis? And if not, if you knew of any best practices for like distributed creds so you can update for multiple lambdas at once?

Comment: @NickKiermaier : per lambda basis thus far. However, the serverless application model recently released could allow for multi-lambda configuration automation and does support environment variables as in this example on github: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/encryption_proxy/template.yaml

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  We're not on serverless YET.  We're trying to learn it from a lower level atm then we may give serverless a shot.